# Regular Expression: Letters, numbers, spaces, hyphens, periods, and underscores only and must begin with a letter

Tags: javascript, regex, keyfilter

After a few tutorials I thought I had this, but nope ---

I am trying to only match a string of letters, numbers, spaces, hyphens, periods, and underscores only and must begin with a letter in a jquery function

This is what I came up with after the tutorials but it only accepts letters:

```
/^[a-z][a-z0-9_ .-]*?/i
```

Please help!

++EDITED++

This is the code where I am trying to use this:

```
$('input[name=albumName]').keyfilter(/^[a-z][a-z0-9_ .-]*?/i);
```

The name that a user is entering will also be used in a URL so I want to limit their entry. I would want this to be allowed ( Texas AandM - 2012 ) but this not to be allowed ( 2012 -  Texas A&M )

Comment: Which language or tool are you using? And you should also add a `$` at the end, otherwise you allow any characters after the beginning letter.

Comment: sorry, didn't realize language made a difference. This is a jquery function to limit values entered into a textbox

Comment: it makes a great difference for certain problems. please include your code that uses the regex and a few example strings that fail to behave as you would like them to.

Comment: You might need to escape the `-`

Comment: `/^[a-z][a-z0-9_ .-]*?/i.test("a0.-_")` works fine, btw. What do you mean by 'only accepts letters'? Are you trying to use `.match` here?

Comment: If the entire string should match, you should use `$` instead of `?`: `/^[a-z][a-z0-9_ .-]*$/i`. The `?` forces the `*` to select minimally, and given its location in the match would mean that `0` characters would be selected.

Comment: zzzzBov, I tried your response and it will only allow letters to be entered -- no numbers, spaces etc. Since this is a jQuery plugin, I am not sure what the function is doing with the entry.

Comment: Your edit completely changes matters here. The problem with 'keyfilter' plugin is just that: it checks the pressed _keys_, and not the whole string. Using sequence in its regex argument is meaningless.

Comment: BTW, have you considered a possibility of user copy-pasting the illegal characters into this input of yours? Keyfilter won't prevent it.

Comment: Note that \*? is a lazy \*, so without the $ at the end, that regular expression will only ever proceed to match the first character, and then attempt to find a match while skipping the lazy "[a-z0-9_ .-]*?", and succeed since nothing follows it.  That regular expression, if I'm not missing something, is equivalent to: "/^[a-z]/i"

Comment: That makes sense. It is only checking one keypress at a time so it will never allow me to satisfy the letter only first requirement. I will have to deal with those elsewhere. THANKS TO ALL!!!

Comment: raina77ow, this is for a password protected CMS of community managers to add photo albums to their websites so I am just trying to stop careless entries. I know that this plug-in is not secure enough to be used in a public environment without further validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex looks ok to me. Perhaps there is a problem with the surrounding code rather than the regex? This is a Python example:

```
s_re = re.compile('^[a-z][a-z0-9_.-]*',re.I) # case insensitive match

In [12]: if s_re.match('A'): print 'match'
match

In [14]: if s_re.match('A.-'): print 'match'
match

In [15]: if s_re.match('1.-'): print 'match'

In [16]: if s_re.match('1_.-'): print 'match'

In [17]: if s_re.match('A_.-'): print 'match'
match
```

If you want to make sure you want at least one character after the first letter, you can replace the `*` with a `+`, or `{2,}` with at least 2 more characters, or `{2,5}` with between 2 and 5 characters.

Answer (score 1):

`^[a-z][a-z0-9_ .-]*` works.

Because of the Question Mark, the Regex matched only letters,
because the match is the smallest possible match.

[Reference/RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_in_regular_expressions)

Comment: When I use /^[a-z0-9_ -]*/i, all requirements are met except must being with a letter. when i change to /^[a-z][a-z0-9_ -]*/i, it stops allowing me to enter anything except letters.

Comment: I know it is this particular jquery plugin that is messing us up and I feel that all of these answers would work in other situations. Thanks to all who are helping!!!